# How to collect all firestore filed value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore and I am trying to collect all field value but I couldn't find a simple way so what I am trying to collect is the total users rates..

So here's an example for what I am looking for:

I need to collect the "rate_value" field:

```html
Rates > Key_A > rate_value: 2
Rates > Key_B > rate_value: 5
Rates > Key_C > rate_value: 1
Rates > Key_D > rate_value: 4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pLl1.png)

So how can I get the total rates (13)..

I have used the code below but it returns me

```
mPostsCollection.document(Post_Key).collection("Rates").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e==null){

                Long Rates = (long) querySnapshot.getDocuments().size();

                for (DocumentSnapshot mDocs : querySnapshot.getDocuments()){

                    Long Rate_Value = mDocs.getLong("rate_value");

                    mPostValue.setText((int) (Rate_Value/Rates));

                }
            }
        }}
    );
```

Comment: anybody body can help me, all what I need is to get the total number of "value" field..

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation):

> Advanced queries in Cloud Firestore allow you to quickly find documents in large collections. If you want to gain insight into properties of the collection as a whole, you will need aggregation over a collection.

So to get the sum of all values, you'll need to [get the documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and add the value of each document.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen check the new changes in the question.